# Slow remote queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am working on a Rails application and was using SQLite during development and the speed had been very fast.

I have started to use a remote MySQL database hosted by Amazon and am getting very slow query times. Besides trying to optimize the remote database, is there anything on the Rails side of things I can do?

Comment: This is pretty open-ended. Do you have anything more specific that we can run tests against? Are you certain that it's SQLite vs. MySQL, e.g. did you test with similar (ideally identical) data in both systems? Are you sure that it's not network time between your Rails app and Amazon?

Comment: Latency can be murder on MySQL queries. Are you sure your server has a good connection to the Amazon database instance?

Answer (score 0):

Local database access vs. remote will show a significant difference in speed.  Since you've not provided any specifics I can't zero in on the issue but I can make a suggestion:

Try [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) your queries and views as much as possible.  This will reduce the amount of queries you need to do.  This works well especially for static data like menus.

[Optimization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) is the key.  Make sure you eliminate as many unnecessary queries as you can, and those queries you make only request the fields you need using the `select` method.

Answer (score 0):

Profile the various components involved. The database server itself is one of them. The network latency is another. While for the second one probably there is little you can do, probably you can tweak alot the first part. Starting from profiling the queries and going to tweaking the server itself.

Knowing where to look for will help you start with the best approach. As for caching, always keep that in mind, but that can prove to be quite problematic depending on the nature of your application.